# Frases para la venta al por menor

Tags: vocabulario, modismos, expresiones

Trabajo en una heladería/gasolinera y hay muchos clientes hispanohablantes y querría un poco de ayuda con algunas frases para el servicio al cliente:

• I’ll ring you out at this register

• I can help you over here

• Your total is.../That’ll be...

• Have you tried...? (para un producto)

• I recommend...

• I can check in the back

• Which pump are you at?

Gracias por la ayuda! Me cuesta intentar pensar cuando tengo un cliente así que este ayudaría muchísimo!

Comment: Hello and welcome to [spanish.se], and thank you for contributing a question! Unfortunately, in its current form, your question may get closed, as it involves multiple questions in a single post. It is also a somewhat subjective question. See [ask] and [tour] to learn more about of approach to the Q&A (question and answers) methodology. Could you [edit] the post to make your question like "is this the proper way of saying this in Spanish"? And please add a new post for each specific, unrelated sentence. Don't hesitate to ask for help if you need it.

Comment: thanks to both of you! i will make sure i do that in the future for sure!!!

Answer (score 2):

Si entendí bien, creo que lo que necesitas es traducir las frases, ¿verdad? Si es así, aquí está mi contribución:

• I’ll ring you out at this register

> Lo atiendo en esta caja.

• I can help you over here.

> Puedo ayudarlo por aquí.

• Your total is.../That’ll be...

> Su cuenta es de...

• Have you tried...? (para un producto)

> ¿Ha probado este producto?

• I recommend...

> Le recomiendo...

• I can check in the back.

> Puedo checar allá atrás.

• Which pump are you at?

> ¿En qué bomba está cargando? (Supongo que está llenando su tanque de gasolina.)

Comment: con “ring you out” quiero decir que puede venir al “cash register” (no sé la palabra) y puedo decirle su cuenta. y tiene razón, quería una traducción ;) muchas gracias!

Comment: Listo. Ya edité mi respuesta y completé tu solicitud. Saludos cordiales.

Comment: muchas muchas gracias por su grande respuesta! la agradezco muchísimo 